# HttpServlet's getParameter("param") return null when there is a value being passed

Tags: java, servlets

I am seeing a strange issue where `request.getParameter("pg")` is returning me null when in the URL I can see its being passed with other parameters. All the other parameters are being printed properly except this one parameter. What could be going wrong?

```
Map<String,String[]> paramMap = (Map<String,String[]>)request.getParameterMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> paramPair : paramMap.entrySet()) {
            LOGGER.info("key - " + paramPair.getKey() + " value =" + paramPair.getValue()[0]);
        }
```

Sample URL -

```
http://myserver?searchfor=History+of+Photography&cb=XQ&n=77de88ca&ptnrS=XQyyyyyyYYus&qid=812753692c6536fb529f5ca7ac5aca9b&action=pick&ss=sub&pn=1&st=hp&ptb=447E5AED-F162-40B4-9EE5-A81299D0223D&plp=1&pg=PRshop&redirect=mPWsrdz9heamc8iHEhldEeSc%2FVOw6SzSGaNI5V3YDA%2F2aJhytHNs8w96Bn6LLIZVUIhPwV62vOCzTXhqJvTnW5g66rsz%2FnxYxdLMAYgDRrDL0jeKlXJQ1pFUFFVXHSrvxvGE971vUn5%2F0m7v9vrFJGEoo6nckfQS9o9CGCHUWndDqD0rhA8TW%2Bfa%2Fpxz8JafQQ3ID%2Fsw6GdCvt65%2FomhgEvEX4xv%2B8XQkfNLNvl6%2BpZdZJshoyUfDw5LZBwzFpw52x0Em9ZDVu1sHm4WxLPt9rDUBHj5Wn0eVf5HNoVYGyCa%2FfufPwfQy8OYiLdgvskMPxUTd3YQOJiiO%2F%2ByMdF4Ew%3D%3D&hlc=YWotbWVnYXx4cS1ocA..&pr=PR&ct=GG&tpr=sbt&tp=top
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: It would help if you added the piece of code thats causing you trouble and the URL that you are sending it.

Comment: Please show us the code making the http request.

Comment: Is this a multivalued parameter? I've run into this issue myself, and the solution is to use the `request.getParameterValues(paramName)` method.

Comment: Not a multivariate value

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Java EE 6 API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) for ServletRequest, getParameter(String) will return `null` if the parameter does not exist.  If you are getting `null` then the parameter does not exist.

Also, the URL example that you included does not demonstrate this error.

Here is the code I used to test:

```
public final class BlueServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6055351295950796407L;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlueServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        PrintWriter responseWriter;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();

        if ((parameterMap != null) && !parameterMap.isEmpty())
        {
            Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry;
            int index;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String[]>> iterator = parameterMap.entrySet().iterator();
            StrBuilder valueBuffer = new StrBuilder();
            String[] values;

            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                entry = iterator.next();
                values = entry.getValue();

                valueBuffer.setLength(0);

                if (values != null)
                {
                    for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index)
                    {
                        valueBuffer.appendSeparator(", ");
                        valueBuffer.append(values[index]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    valueBuffer.append("[none]");
                }

                logger.info("Key: {}; Value(s): {}", entry.getKey(), valueBuffer);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("parameterMap is empty.");
        }

        responseWriter = response.getWriter();
        responseWriter.println("<html><head><title>Blue</title></head><body>");
        responseWriter.println("<h1>Blue</h1></body>");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I know it does not make sense and I would not have believed it either if I would not have seen it for myself. I am still seeing request.getParameter("pg") returning null but request.getQueryString() is returning me the entire string including pg param value. I am using JDK 5 and tomcat version 5.5.12.

Comment: @Shamik Do you maybe iterate over parameter map (for example for purposes of logging)and use iterator remove?

Comment: @Shamik i am facing similar issue, may you comment, what was the root cause of ur issue ?